# os.PathLike[Any] vs os.PathLike[str]

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, python-3.9

I've seen lines like that in typeshed:

https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/994b69ef8f18e76689daca3947879c3d7f76173e/stdlib/_typeshed/__init__.pyi#L77

But [os.PathLike](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8f6aa48cb2dc827a2cb76e35e91bf02d099875c5/Lib/os.py?_pjax=%23repo-content-pjax-container#L1070-L1085) doesn't appear to be generic. It doesn't let strings be passed.

```
import os
import pathlib

def test(f: os.PathLike[str]):
    print(pathlib.Path(f))


test(r"C:\Program Files")
```

The above snippet [fails Mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=c545c024822367c1aac0fe2af753942c).

Comment: You should really transcribe the relevant code snippets from typeshed (besides including the link). Python is open source so it's ok, and it makes the question more self-contained and better for the readers.

Answer (score 8):

The source code that you link to in your question shows that `os.PathLike` is an Abstract Base Class that has a single `abstractmethod`, `__fspath__`. Due to the implementation of `__subclasshook__`, any classes that define `__fspath__` are considered to be subclasses of `os.PathLike` even if `PathLike` is not in the class's method resolution order.

The `str` data type, however, does not have an `__fspath__` method. As such, it does not conform to the `PathLike` interface, and so it makes sense that MyPy should reject an argument of type `str` if an argument of type `PathLike` was expected.

If your function can accept either a `str` object or a `PathLike` object, you should annotate the argument as being of type `Union[str, PathLike[str]]`, [much as typeshed does here](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/994b69ef8f18e76689daca3947879c3d7f76173e/stdlib/_typeshed/__init__.pyi#L77).

As an aside, I'm slightly confused as to why you say "`os.PathLike` doesn't appear to be generic". The class defines `__class_getitem__`, so it's perfectly parametriseable at runtime. In Python >= 3.9:

```
>>> from os import PathLike
>>> PathLike[str]
os.PathLike[str]
>>> PathLike[bytes]
os.PathLike[bytes]
>>> PathLike['idk, anything you like really']
os.PathLike['idk, anything you like really']
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess I was wondering what the significance of [str] or [bytes] was. It's the return type of `__fspath__` - so I thought str would be automatically allowed by mypy since `PathLike[str]` means "a class with a named function that returns a `str`", so I assumed passing a str instead would be deemed acceptable.

Comment: @Greedo yeah, I'd always look at the typeshed stubs over the cpython source code if you want to find out the significance of `[str]`, `[bytes]`, etc. The runtime source code doesn't have any type hints at all; if you want to find out *why* a class is parametriseable, and what that means in terms of type-hinting, I'd always go look at the typeshed stubs :)